# Visual Studio Code - Jump to file

Tags: visual-studio-code

In PhpStorm and Netbeans, I can easily jump to a file by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking on the path e.g. clicking on the path in the following `include`

```
<?php
    include("site/foo/bar.phtml")
?>
```

Does this also work in Visual Studio Code? It does not work if I hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on it.

Comment: is this for php only?

Comment: I only use it for php, js, css, html, phtml until now. But it would be great if there is a solution for every language.

Comment: I think you need to install the specific language extension for this

Comment: I installed many intelli sense extensions, but none of them helped.